# android Sqlite datatime datatype

Tags: android, datetime, sqlite

Which is the best datatype to be used for creating a datetime field like in MysQL ?

i wanna store in this format YYYYMMDD HHMMSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no DATE format in SQLite3, so you should store your date time in string. Format should just reflect your need. If you don't want to store time, DDMMYYYY will be enough.

Just format the date before saving and parse the string when reading from db.

Comment: so basicaly i can use this statement and not mention the format. db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE mails (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, pid INTEGER DEFAULT '0', from_id INTEGER, to_id INTEGER, subject TEXT, body TEXT, datetime TEXT, read INTEGER);");  i am coming from mysql background so plz excuse me.